# Autodesk Forge Data connector incomplete csv files of request

Tags: autodesk-forge

when requesting the data zip file from de servicegroups admin, issues, assets the autodesk forge api doesnt return all .csv. files. im missing assets.csv.

could somebody tell me what i am doing wrong.
Output of the request:

[image: output of the request]

Comment: Hi, Asset data has not been officially released with Data Connector. The readme.html also tells it is unsupported yet. While yes, it is scheduled it will be supported in the future. I also logged the problem with engineer team at DATACON-370. We will ensure the data can work well when it is officially released.   At this moment, I would suggest with Asset API https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/bim-360-assets-api-public-beta-here Thank you for reporting this problem and understanding!

Comment: regarding with Asset API, I produced one sample that export all data to Excel. It may not be exactly in the same format like Data Connector does, while may be of use currently : https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-bim360.asset.exchange.excel